# Windows Authentication on IIS with ZAP

Tags: iis, windows-authentication, zap

I'm unable to use ZAP proxy with web application after enabling SSL. Application uses windows Authentication. Was working fine before enabling SSL. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

```
2016-03-23 11:09:00,158 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO  Control - New Session
2016-03-23 11:09:58,219 [Thread-16] WARN  ProxyListenerLog - java.sql.SQLException: The actual Response Body length 5510728 is greater than the configured response body length 1024000
org.parosproxy.paros.db.DatabaseException: java.sql.SQLException: The actual Response Body length 5510728 is greater than the configured response body length 1024000
    at org.parosproxy.paros.db.paros.ParosTableHistory.write(Unknown Source)
    at org.parosproxy.paros.model.HistoryReference.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.parosproxy.paros.extension.history.ProxyListenerLog.addHistory(Unknown Source)
    at org.parosproxy.paros.extension.history.ProxyListenerLog.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at org.parosproxy.paros.extension.history.ProxyListenerLog$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: The actual Response Body length 5510728 is greater than the configured response body length 1024000
    at org.parosproxy.paros.db.paros.ParosTableHistory.write(Unknown Source)
    ... 6 more
2016-03-23 11:10:07,694 [ZAP-ProxyThread-12] ERROR HttpMethodDirector - Out of sequence NTLM response message
org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.MalformedChallengeException: Out of sequence NTLM response message
    at org.zaproxy.zap.network.ZapNTLMScheme.processChallenge(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.AuthChallengeProcessor.processChallenge(AuthChallengeProcessor.java:162)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.processWWWAuthChallenge(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.processAuthenticationResponse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
    at org.parosproxy.paros.network.HttpSender.executeMethod(Unknown Source)
    at org.parosproxy.paros.network.HttpSender.runMethod(Unknown Source)
    at org.parosproxy.paros.network.HttpSender.send(Unknown Source)
    at org.parosproxy.paros.network.HttpSender.sendAuthenticated(Unknown Source)
    at org.parosproxy.paros.network.HttpSender.sendAndReceive(Unknown Source)
    at org.parosproxy.paros.network.HttpSender.sendAndReceive(Unknown Source)
    at org.parosproxy.paros.core.proxy.ProxyThread.processHttp(Unknown Source)
    at org.parosproxy.paros.core.proxy.ProxyThread.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```